How can I convert a non-local potential $V (r, r') $ into a local but energy-dependent potential, i.e., $V (r, E) $?
I need to localize a nuclear non-local potential. Using both these non-local and local potential in the Schrödinger equation we should have approximately close eigenvalues.
I tried the way followed by Mahaux and Sartor and described in their book chapter, Single-Particle Motion in Nuclei (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-9910-0_1)
